# Адрес "noreply@inform-policy.com" в поле "ОТ" уведомлений

Tags: javamail, alfresco

Доброго дня! Alfresco Community - 5.2.0,  alvex-3.0-20170306.120406-196
Если в настройках alfresco-global.properties не добавлять строчку

```
mail.from.enable=false
```

То уведомления о загрузке файла приходят от адресата noreply@inform-policy.com, даже несмотря  на то, что строчка:

```
mail.from.default= alfresco@"MYDOMAIN".ru
```

присутствует.

Команда:

```
grep -r "noreply@inform-policy.com" /opt/alfresco-community
```

результата не даёт. В каком модуле настраивается этот адрес по умолчанию и как проще всего это отследить?

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте в `alfresco-global.properties` строку:

```
documentchangeinform.mail.from=alfresco@"MYDOMAIN".ru
```

Для отправки уведомлений об изменении файлов берется значение этой переменной.